# R setting a new value to the default argument for a function

Tags: r, function

I have written a function in R like this:

```
foo <- function(a, b = 1) {
    ...
}
```

But now I want to change the default argument b, like:

```
foo(b = 2)
```

This is a function of a in principle. But R doesn't allow this, which throws me an error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: R allows it. The error comes from not passing the mandatory argument `a`. (Mandatory if used in the function body.) If you want to omit `a` you will have to assign it a default value too.

Answer (score 6):

Your code in `foo(b = 2)` is function application: if everything works as expected, it will give you a value rather than a function.

You can modify the default values of arguments using `formals`:

```
foo <- function(a, b = 1) {
  a + b
}

formals(foo)$b <- 2
foo
#function (a, b = 2) 
# {
#     a + b
# }
```

If you don't want to modify your `foo` directly, there are several options:

1) Copy first, change later

```
foa <- foo
formals(foa)$b <- 42
```

One might think of using `"formals<-"` as a shortcut but that can be complicated as you need to supply the full list of arguments (using `alist` rather than `list` because the former can take an empty argument):

```
"formals<-"(foo, , list(b=2))  # trying it with `list` 
function (b = 2)  # we lost one argument! 
{
    a + b
} 
"formals<-"(foo, , alist(a=, b=42))  # this one is better!
function (a, b = 42) 
{
  a + b
}
```

2) Use  `purr::partial` or `function(a) foo(a,b=42)` as recommended in the other answer.

3) And a third way ... one can actually write a very simple function (I'll call it `p2`) that changes *some* of the default arguments of a function and returns the changed function:

```
p2 <- function(f, l){
  formals(f)[names(l)] <- l
  f
}

p2(foo, list(b=42)) # changing a default: function (a, b = 42) a+b
p2(foo, alist(b=)) # removing a default: function (a, b) a+b
p2(foo, list(c="bingo") # adding an argument: function (a, b = 2, c = "bingo") a+b
```

A modified version:

```
p3 <- function(f, ...){
  l <- as.list(sys.call())[-(1L:2L)]  # code from `alist`
  formals(f)[names(l)] <- l
  f
  }
```

Now the usage becomes shorter:

```
p3(foo, b=43) # function (a, b = 43) a+b
p3(foo, b=) # function(a,b) a+b
```

Note that `p2` and `p3` won't work properly with generic functions such as `mean` and `min`. This is probably the reason why the code in `purrr:partial` is so much more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `foo` as so: `foo(a, b = whatever)`

If you need to change the default `b` to the same value really often, you could make a new `foo`-related function.

You could either define a new function:

```
# partially substitute in a `b` value
goo <- purrr::partial(foo, b = 2, .first = FALSE)

# or, a bit more explicitly,
hoo <- function(a) {foo(a, b = 2)}
```

or construct a function builder/[factory](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html), that allows you to build as many foo-related functions as you like

```
foo_builder <- function(b = 1) {
  function(a) {
    # your definition of foo goes here
    blah <- blah_f(a, b)
  }
}
```

Now you can pass in a `b` value to foo_builder and it will return the equivalent function to `foo(a, b = whatever_you_passed_to_foo_builder)`

```
goo <- foo_builder(2)
goo(a = ...)
```

For example,

```
foo_builder <- function(b = 1){
   function(a){
     message(b)
     a + b
   }
 }
```

Now when the internal function is defined by foo_builder, it takes the value of `b` that is available to the `foo_builder` environment. This is 1 by default, but can be changed.

For example,

```
# default
foo_builder()(1)
1
[1] 2

# with b=2 in the closure returned by foo_builder
b <- 2
fb <- foo_builder(b)
fb(1)
2
[1] 3
```

A commenter suggested that you ought to force the evaluation of `b` when you make closures this way; because of the following:

```
b <- 2
fb <- foo_builder(b)
b <- 3
fb(1)
# 3
# [1] 4
```

So maybe rewrite the foo_builder:

```
foo_builder <- function(b = 1){
   force(b)
   function(a){
     message(b)
     a + b
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should call `force(b)` in your `foo_builder` solution, or else it won't be evaluated until the first call to `goo`.  So `b <- 2; goo <- foo_builder(b); b <- 3; goo(...)` will result in `goo` being created with `b = 3`.